# Rewrite subdomain to subfolder causes loop error or 403

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a local Apache server set up on my machine, with wildcard DNS in place. I have it set up so that it works like `[foldername].loc`. So, for instance, a folder under my `htdocs` folder called `MyDomain`, would be accessed via `mydomain.loc`. This code works fine, and the code in my `.htaccess` in my `htdocs` is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]*\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %3::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule (.*) /%3/$1 [PT,QSA]
```

Now, the above code also passes through subdomains, such as "john.mydomain.loc". Now, I have the following folder structure in the folder `MyDomain`:

```
MyDomain
    - active
        - index.php
    - working
        - index.php
    .htaccess
```

In the `.htaccess` of `MyDomain` is the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.mydomain\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /active/$1 [L]
```

What this should do, if I understand correctly, is take `http://live.mydomain.loc/` and rewrite it to be `http://mydomain.loc/active/`. Note that I said **rewrite**, not **redirect**.

With the code above, however, I get a message in the Apache error log:

```
[client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

If I change the `.htaccess` of `MyDomain` to read as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.mydomain\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /active/$1 [L]
```

When I use this code, it always comes up with a 403 error, saying I don't have permission to view the folder `/mydomain/`. If I set `Options +Indexes`, I only see the folder index of `/mydomain`. So where along the line is the above code failing?

I have also tried the above code with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/active/`. This has made no difference in the results.

I have tried this for over two days, and I can't figure it out. I hope the brilliant minds of StackOverflow can help figure this out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the rewrite base to where the file actually is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MyDomain/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.mydomain\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ active/$1 [L]
```

And making the `/active/` relative: `active/`

Comment: Thanks, and whilst I feel we're on the right track, it hasn't quite worked. This is an excerpt out of my rewrite log file: `internal redirect with /mydomain/active/active/active/active/active/active/active/active/active/active/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]` This is the last line of the log, and apparently we've missed a loop point somewhere. Any thoughts?

Comment: I figured it out. I've submitted it as an answer. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.mydomain\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain/active/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ active/$1 [L]
```

The primary fix was `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain/active/`. The difference is, the first line I tried, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/active`, would match `/access/index.php`, but not `/mydomain/active/index.php`.

I hope this helps someone else.